# How can you raise temperatures to extreme levels

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, optimization, environmental-hazards

I'm looking for ways to raise the temperature of my surroundings. Wherever I go, water should evaporate, buffalo should drop dead and become nothing but skulls and the soil should become sand.

I'm going the Walker in the Waste build, so I already have the environment within 100' of me raised to Severe Heat. I'd like to increase that as a permanent effect. Any level is fine, but not epic.

How extremely hot can I get my local environment to become?

Comment: More information about your current build idea will narrow this question some.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, let's take a look at the [heat scale](https://wiki.rpg.net/index.php/DnD_Desert_Raiders_Campaign_Heat_Dangers):

[image: Heat Scale]

Let's assume that you are starting in a moderate environement - Medium temperature - and want to ramp up the heat as much as possible. You are also level 14, enough to easily get the Greater Drought skill ([Walker in the Waste](http://alcyius.com/dndtools/classes/walker-in-the-waste/index.html) level 9) and therefore have 13 caster levels.

> Beginning at 9th level, you can produce extreme desert conditions in a
>   100-foot radius emanation with you at the center. The temperature band
>   in that area rises by two steps or to severe heat, whichever produces
>   the hotter result.

**I would recommend using the spell [Control Temperature](http://dokdorspace.com/dndtools/spells/frostburn--68/control-temperature--1303/index.html) from the Frostburn book.**

> You imbue an area with cold or fire energy, reducing or raising the temperature by one temperature band per five caster levels.

This lasts for 1 hour/level and has a 20ft/level radius which should be at least 13 hours per casting across a 260ft radius. As a relatively low level spell (third) you should be able to prep multiple castings if needs be.

There are two interpretations of the effects below, depending on whether the spell or the ability are applied to your environment first, but the end result is much the same.

If you add further caster levels, or start in a warmer climate, then you can raise the heat up by another band or two relatively easily.

**Greater Drought first**

Greater drought raises the temperature in the area to at least [severe heat](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Environment#Heat_Dangers) immediately, and at caster level 13 the spell will raise it by a further two heat levels.

At this point you are in Unearthly Heat and everything around you that is breathing will start dying *very* quickly.

> In this temperature band, which includes many environments normally
>   deadly to all life, unprotected characters take 1d6 points of lethal
>   damage and 1d4 points of nonlethal damage per round (no save). In
>   addition, those wearing metal armor or coming into contact with very
>   hot metal are affected as if by a heat metal spell (which lasts as
>   long as the character remains in the area of unearthly heat).

**Control Temperature first**

Starting at Moderate you would add two heat levels from the spell, putting you into the 'Hot' category. Greater Drought then raises this by two steps, taking you into Extreme Heat where everything around you that is breathing will start dying rather quickly, although not as quickly as with the previous example.

Comment: When order matters, typically the controller of the effects decides the order to their best benefit. This is a rule of thumb rather than a rule, and it comes from an FAQ entry or similar rather than a published book, but it might be worth adding to indicate that it would be at least somewhat valid to favor the stronger interpretation.

Comment: @KRyan do you have a source for that? I'd be happy to add it in.